# Quotient Group G/G = {identity}?

Tags: group-theory

I know this is a basic question, but I'm trying to convince myself of Wikipedia's statement. **"The quotient group $G / G$ is isomorphic to the trivial group."**

I write the definition for left multiplication because left cosets = right cosets. $ G/G = \{g \in G : gG\} $ But how is this isomorphic to the trivial group, $ \{id_G\} $? $gG$ can't be simplified to $id_G$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: How many cosets are there?

Comment: Isomorphic, not equal.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, forgive me for getting all technical, but this isn't right: $G/G = \{ g \in G \colon gG\}$. It should be the other way around: $G/G = \{ gG |\, g \in G \}$.

Next, we get rid of $g$ by realizing that $gG = G$ for any $g \in G$. Therefore, $G/G = \{G\}$, i.e. $G/G$ is a set with exactly 1 element, and this element is $G$ itself.

Now, the next thing is to realize how the operation in $G/G = \{G\}$ works. It works like this: $G \cdot G = G$. Exactly like that of the trivial group $\{1\}$: $1 \cdot 1 = 1$. So, the map $G/G \to \{1\}$ that sends $G$ to $1$ is a group isomorphism.

I know, I know, this may be the worst way to explain these things. There are way too many trivial formulas there. But it can be good for convincing oneself of something.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the zero homomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow G$. Then the $\ker\phi=G$, $\mathrm{Im}\phi =\left\{id_G\right\}$ and from the first theorem of Isomorphism $\frac{G}{\ker\phi}\cong \mathrm{Im}\phi$ which of course implies that $G/G\cong \left\{id_G\right\}$

Comment: Correct, concise answer.  Nice.

Comment: And probably best explanation for OP who confuses $G$ with {$G$}, and equal with isomorphic.

Comment: Except that he is just starting to learn about quotient groups, does he know what a kernel is, or the relationship between kernel and quotients? If he doesn't understand what $G/G$ is, does he understand the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: I was being sarcastic...good, clean answer, but no good given context.

Comment: @gnometorule Ah, sarcasm is hard to read sometimes online. :)

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: It's probably because I'm German. German attempts at humor tend to fail miserably.

Comment: @gnometorule I got your sarcasm and upvoted. Maybe it's somehow related to the fact that I'm Russian )

Comment: Thank you for the zero homomorphism. I think I get it now.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.

Answer (score 6):

$\operatorname{id}_G$ is not an element of $G/G$. The elements of $G/G$ are sets of the form $gG$ with $g\in G$. But $gG=G$ for all $g\in G$, so there is only one co-set.

Now you just have to convince yourself that all groups with only one element are isomorphic. That's pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it will help you to first look at a different quotient group, and then look at $G/G$.

Suppose that you have a subgroup $H$ of $G$ which is exactly half the size of $G$.  The factor group $G/H$ is the *set of cosets of H in G*.  What are these cosets?

If you multiply everything in $H$ by an element that is in $H$, you get back $H$.  If you do the same with some fixed $g_0\in G$ such that $g_0\notin H$, the resulting coset $g_0H=\{g_0h : h \in H\}$ has no elements in common with $H$.  (If it did have some $g_0h\in H$, by closure $g_0hh^{-1}=g_0\in H$, a contradiction.)  Since $g_0H$ is the same size as $H$, which is half the size of $G$, $H$ and $g_0H$ together make up all the elements of $G$. This means that for any $g'\in G$ you pick, either $g'H=H$ or $g'H=g_0H$; in other words, these are the only two cosets.

So we have that $G/H=\{H, g_0H\}$.  The operation for a factor group is $(aH)(bH)=(ab)H$, for any two cosets $aH,bH\in G/H$.  So, for example, $(g_0H)(g_0H)=(g_0^2)H$.  (For the coset "$H$" it's easiest to think of it as having an invisible $\text{id}_G$, so $(g_0H)(H)=(g_0\text{id}_G)H=g_0H$.  Thus we have that $H=\text{id}_{G/H}$.)  In particular, $G/H$ is a group with $2$ elements, so we know that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ because that is the only group of order $2$.

Now let's try doing it with $G/G$.

Well, $gG=G$ for any $g\in G$.  So that is the only coset.  Thus $G/G=\{G\}$, and $\text{id}_{G/G}=G$.  It has only one element, so it must be isomorphic to the only group with one element, the trivial group.

Comment: Thank you. I'll spend some time looking over this.

Comment: The last line is the most clear answer here for sure!

Answer (score 3):

$G/G$ has only one element, which is $G$. Therefore this group is trivial.

Comment: Thanks. I understand $ G/G  = \{\text{all elements in G}\} =  G $ but how does $ G/G = id_G $?

Comment: There's a difference between $G$ and {$G$}. Answer says/means {$G$}; you $G$.

Comment: @Peterundergrad $G=\text{id}_{G/G}$, not $\text{id}_G$, and $G/G\not= \{\text{stuff in }G\}$, $G/G=\{gG:g\in G\}=\{G\}$.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If G is a group and N is normal in G, then G/N is the quotient group. G/N as a group consists of cosets of the normal subgroup N in G and these cosets themselves satisfy the group properties because of normality of N. Now G is clearly normal in G. Hence G/G consists of the coset that is all of G. Thus this group has only one element, thence it must be isomorphic to the identity group

Answer (score 2):

$G/G=id_G$ is false. It should be $G/G=\{[id_G]\}$ And actually you could use any element, where the [] mean the equivalence class. Saying G/G=all elements in G is also false, it should be that G/G is a group containing only one element, that is a set that contains all elements in G.

If we go to the definition of quotient group $xy^{-1}\in G\forall x,y\in G$, then, as all elements are related to each other and there's only one equivalence class, therefore the group G/G has one element. As it has one element and the identity must be in the group, then that element is the identity, but it's the identity of the group G/G, not the identity of the group G. The isomorphism G/G->{1} is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The notation of quotient group such $G/N$ is beautiful, but often misleads us to forget that $G/N$ is no more than a group where its elements are cosets $gN$ defined as:

> For $N \unlhd G$ and $g \in G$ then $gN = \{gn \: | \: n \in N\}$.

Identity of the group is $N$. For elements $aN, bN \in G/N$, where $a, b \in G$, are considered the same element $aN = bN$ if $ab^{-1} \in N$.

In the case of $N = G$, we have that the identity of the group is element $G$. For $a, b \in G$, we ALWAYS have that $ab^{-1} \in G$. That means no matter which elements we choose they are always the same element $G$. So this new group $G/G$ has only one element $G$ which is also its identity. Written explicitly $G/G = \{G\} \cong \{1\}$.